# images re-render and slow performance in react app once the app was opened

Tags: reactjs, image, performance, react-hooks, lazy-loading

When navigating away from and returning to my React website, the images are being re-rendered, resulting in a noticeable lag in performance. This issue is particularly evident when reopening the app, causing it to feel sluggish and unresponsive.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { Url, Url_img, en } from "../hooks";
import { flexing } from "../utils";

type Item = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  img_url: string;
  category_id: number;
  focus_row: number;
  focus_colm: number;
  focus_width: number;
};

type ItemSet = {
  items: Item[];
};

const MemoizedImage = React.memo(
  ({ src, alt }: { src: string; alt: string }) => (
    <img
      className="image"
      loading="lazy"
      src={`${Url_img}/${src}`}
      alt={alt}
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        objectFit: "cover",
      }}
    />
  )
);

const Hero = () => {
  const { isPending, error, data } = useQuery<ItemSet[]>({
    queryKey: ["focusdata"],
    queryFn: () => fetch(`${Url}/${en}/focus`).then((res) => res.json()),
  });

  if (isPending)
    return (
      <div className="w-full flex justify-center my-9">
        <div className="loader flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
          <span className="loader-text">loading</span>
          <span className="load"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;

  return (
    <section className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center mt-20 ml-14">
      <div style={{ width: "65%", margin: "auto" }} className="">
        {data && data.length > 0 ? (
          data.map((itemSet, setIndex) => (
            <div key={setIndex} className="flex">
              {itemSet?.items?.map((item) => (
                <div
                  key={item?.id}
                  style={{
                    display: "inline-block",
                    margin: "8px",
                    width: `${item.focus_width}%`,
                    height: "300px",
                    overflow: "hidden",
                    position: "relative",
                  }}
                  className="cursor-pointer relative hover-div"
                >
                  <MemoizedImage src={item?.img_url} alt={item?.name} />
                  <p className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 text-white uppercase transition text-lg w4  hover:text-black">
                    {item?.name}
                  </p>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div className={`${flexing}`}>
            <p className="w7">No data available</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

I tried use Memo , and image lazy loading but the results were the same.

Comment: Memoizing html `img` tag doesn't do anything for performance. Memoization only works with react components.

Comment: Is your list too big ? If so, Try creating a separate component for the part of your code which renders for each list item and  memoize  that component.